# No puedo mostrar y eliminar un registro mediante una ventana emergente

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

La función eliminar funciona perfectamente haciendo lo siguiente con el botón de eliminar.

```
<a href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $persona->id; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="<?php $identificador = $persona->id; ?>">Eliminar</button></a>
```

como podrán notar envio un parámetro a mi archivo **borrar.php**

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
try{
    $sql="delete from datos_usuarios where id='$id'";
    $execute = $base->query($sql);
    header ('Location: index.php');

}catch(Exception $e){
    die ('Error no se ah podido eliminar el usuario' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Viendo la simpleza de mi programa decidí agregar un modal bootstrap en el cual se muestra la información de la persona que deseo eliminar y dos botones, uno para confirmar que esta seguro de eliminar el registro y el otro para cancelar dicha acción.

El problema es que no encuentro la forma de mostrar la información de la persona que fue seleccionada, se me ocurrió que al momento de dar click al botón de eliminar almacenar en una variable el id del registro que intento eliminar de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="#ventana1" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onClick="$identificador = $persona->id; ?>" >Eliminar</button></a>
```

Como podrán entender soy novato en php y la verdad no encuentro error alguno pero creo que tiene que ver con que no se esta asignando el valor a la variable, bueno pues sin mas  un abrazo a todos, adjunto todo el código de mi archivo **índex.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<?php

include ('conexion.php');

$registros  = $base->query('SELECT * FROM DATOS_USUARIOS')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
<h3 class="text-center">Registro de usuarios</h3>
  <div class="container">

      <!--VENTANA MODAL -->

      <div class="modal fade" id="ventana1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="">Eliminar usuario</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <?php
                      $resultado = $base->query("select * from datos_usuarios where id='$identificador' limit 1")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                      foreach($resultado as $rs){
                          echo "Esta seguro que desea eliminar el usuario <b>" . $rs->nombre . "</b>";
                      }

                      ?>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <a href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $identificador; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="">Eliminar</button></a>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!--END MODAL -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Formulario de registro</div>
          <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="table table-responsive text-center">
              <table class ="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellido</th>
                  <th>Direccion</th>
                  <th>Opciónes</th>
                </thead>
                  <?php
                  foreach($registros as $persona):?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $persona->id?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $persona->nombre?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $persona->apellido?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $persona->direccion?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="actualizar.php"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Actualizar</button></a>
                        <a href="#ventana1" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onClick="$identificador = $persona->id; ?>" >Eliminar</button></a>
                        <!-- <a href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $persona->id; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="<?php $identificador = $persona->id; ?>">Eliminar</button></a> -->
                    </td>

                </tr>
                  <?php
                  endforeach;
                    ?>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="" value=""></td>
                    <td><div class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Insertar</button>

                        </div></td>
                </tr>
              </table>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que incluir esa información en un html que será mostrado cuando pulses ese botón, ahí puedes definir la información que quieras y las acciones de los botones.

Revisa la página de la documentación.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Escribes el html del modal en alguna parte de la página y en el botón le indicas cual es con data-target="#myModal".

En tu caso tendrías que escribir un modal por cada entrada de la tabla. Otra alternativa sería consultar esos datos dinámicamente con ajax y poblar el modal dinámicamente, en ese caso sólo tendrías que escribir un modal vacío en html.

Leyendo tu código parece que quieres ejecutar el php después de procesarlo, haciendo click desde el navegador, y eso no es posible, necesitas hacerlo con javascript.

Mete el código html del modal dentro del bucle   y asígnale a cada modal un id, que corresponda con el parámetro data-target de cada botón.